# Difference between $E_p$ and $ΔE_p$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, potential-energy, conventions

Inside my textbook there are two potential energy formulas, what is the difference between $E_p$ and $ΔE_p$ and *when* do we use them?

$$E_p = \frac{1}{2}k\Delta x^2$$
$$\Delta E_p = mg\Delta h$$

Comment: what is the meaning of k? and x?

Considering that x is the height and k=mg then $\Delta E_p$
is the derivative of $E_p$, with respect to x 
So $\frac{dE_p(x)}{x} = kx=...$

Comment: It looks like the first equation is for elastic potential energy and the second is for change in gravitational potential energy.

Comment: Aren't these formulae explained in your textbook?

Answer (score 4):

*You are mixing together two types of potential energies here: be aware that $E_p=\frac12 k x^2$ is **elastic** potential energy, while $E_p=mgh$ is **gravitational** potential energy. Below I answer for the gravitational case first and end off with the elastic case.*

---

The notation suggests that $E_p$ is an **absolute** value, and $\Delta E_p$ a **difference** between two absolute values (something like $\Delta E_p=E_{p2}-E_{p1}$).

But there is an issue with absolute values of gravitational potential energies: *you can't calculate them!* Any absolute value $E_p$ always depends on some *reference*, so in fact it is nothing more than the difference from that reference value.

- The **absolute** value of *gravitational* potential energy is: $$E_p=mgy\qquad \text{or more generally}\qquad E_p=-G\frac{Mm}{y}$$ You can't calculate this without defining a coordinate system to give you a value of $y$. And defining a coordinate system means choosing a reference. So, although the absolute value as a concept exists, it is never useful because you don't have an objective reference and thus can't get an objective "absolute value" of potential energy.
- The **difference** between two absolute values $\Delta E_p$ is therefore the only useful concept. For example, think of the simple version of *the energy conservation law*: $$E_{k,1}+E_{p,1}=E_{k,2}+E_{p,2}$$ All kinetic energy $E_k$ and potential energy $E_p$ at a point in time is the same at any other point in time; they can convert into other forms of energy but the total energy is unchanged. Now, both $E_{p,1}$ and $E_{p,2}$ are written as absolute values here. We can't calculate them; **but that doesn't matter**. We just need to know the **change**. If 10 Joules of potential energy is lost, then 10 Joules of kinetic energy must have been gained. In other words, the rewriting is: $$E_{k,1}+E_{p,1}=E_{k,2}+E_{p,2} \qquad \Leftrightarrow \\ E_{p,1}-E_{p,2}=E_{k,2}-E_{k,1} \qquad \Leftrightarrow \\ \Delta E_p=-\Delta E_k$$

The *difference* (or *change*) is way more interesting than the actual absolute values.

If you do try to calculate the absolute values of potential energies, then you will have to choose a reference/coordinate system. And this is okay to do, if you just uses the same reference for all potential energies - because then, again, the absolute value itself is some arbitrary value that depends on your arbitrary choice of reference and is thus uninteresting and tells us nothing, but we can still subtract two potential energies and see what the difference is. And *that* is useful.

---

In the other case you have, you are referring to **elastic** potential energy. In a spring for example.

Now, in the formula $$E_p=\frac12 k x^2$$ at first glance it looks like we have the same issue with a choice of reference as before for gravitational potential energy. Because $x$ must have a starting point - a coordinate system - before we can have a value for it. But in this case the choice of reference is much more intuitive. We of course place our coordinate system to start at the point where the spring **is unstretched**, because this is the point where no energy is stored.

So in this case it *does* make sense to talk about an absolute value of potential energy. The objective reference is obvious here, while it wasn't obvious in the gravitational case. There exist many types of potential energies, and each may be different in this way.

Comment: I think you are missing a negative sign in the general equation for $E_g$.